# Why do Germans write "Good morning in the morning"?

Tags: salutation

This English sentence keeps being used by colleagues of mine at work (in emails) and I've no idea why it's used and if they realize that it doesn't make any kind of sense in English. Is this a widespread thing? Am I missing some cultural reference?

Comment: I'm a native German speaker. I've never heard of this and it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I think this should be a pun... a very stupid pun ;)

Comment: I don't see the relation to the German languge, thus I vote close.

Comment: If your colleagues write that in English, what makes you think Germans do that?

Comment: @puck: the colleagues seem to be German, see the headline.

Answer (score 2):

Never heard of it before, but after googling it, it seems to be related to [Michael Wendler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Wendler), a German singer, songwriter and reality show participant.

[See this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wwav31lHkWU&ab_channel=DeutscheMemes)